# Google Apps Script doPost image object empty

Tags: google-apps-script, post, inline-images

I have a deployed Web App on a generic Google account I wish to work as a mail server for automation projects.
It works well but I can't get inlineImages objects to carry over the POST request. The image object always comes through empty. Can someone explain what's up and whether there's a way to carry images over a POST request to include (inline) in emails for use with a GAS Web App like this one?

Server code (simplified):

```
function doPost(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  const { apikey, recipient, subject, body, images } = data;

  console.log(images) // Always outputs {'img_map: {}}

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "", {name: "TSL mail server", htmlBody: body, inlineImages: images});
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Email sent successfully.');
}
```

Client code:

```
// DriveApp.getFiles()
function myPost() {
  const map = DriveApp.getFileById(MYFILE_ID).getAs('image/png');
  const postData = {
    'apikey': APIKEY,
    'recipient': 'me@example.com',
    'subject': 'Testing GAS mail server',
    'body': '<h1>Hello, Mail World!</h1><img src="cid:img_map"/>',
    'images': {'img_map': map}
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'POST',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(postData),
    'headers': { Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MAIL_ENDPOINT, options);
  console.log(response.getResponseCode());
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to request from the function `myPost` to `doPost`. The value of `MAIL_ENDPOINT` is the Web Apps URL of `doPost`.
- You have already been able to request to `doPost` using your `myPost` while the value of `images` is not correctly sent.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the image file is sent as base64 data. The modified script is as follows.

#### `doPost`

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  let { apikey, recipient, subject, body, images } = data;
  images = { img_map: Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(images.img_map), 'image/png') };

  console.log(images) // Always outputs {'img_map: {}}

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, "", { name: "TSL mail server", htmlBody: body, inlineImages: images });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('Email sent successfully.');
}
```

#### `myPost`

```js
function myPost() {
  const map = Utilities.base64Encode(DriveApp.getFileById(MYFILE_ID).getAs('image/png').getBytes());
  const postData = {
    'apikey': APIKEY,
    'recipient': 'me@example.com',
    'subject': 'Testing GAS mail server',
    'body': '<h1>Hello, Mail World!</h1><img src="cid:img_map"/>',
    'images': { 'img_map': map }
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(postData),
    'headers': { Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}` },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(MAIL_ENDPOINT, options);
  console.log(response.getResponseCode());
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

- When this modified script is used and `myPost` is run, the values of `postData` are sent to `doPost`. And, at `doPost`, the image file is decoded from base64 data and used with `inlineImages`.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that the variables of `MYFILE_ID`, `APIKEY`, and `MAIL_ENDPOINT` have already been declared elsewhere and those values are valid values. Please be careful about this.
- **When you modify the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the details of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### References:

- [base64Encode(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64encodedata)
- [base64Decode(encoded)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Decode(String))

Comment: What an absolute honor to be saved by Mr. Tanaike. Really appreciate it and the suggested file coding/encoding was the missing link for me. All your assumptions were correct. I ended up doing away with mimetype and adding a hack-n-slash image-only mimetype detector on the server side inspired heavily by this repository by Huyên Nguyen, https://github.com/huyennbl/base64-image-mime